# How to store value pairs in java script?

Tags: javascript

I need to store the below value pairs like in java script.
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)
1750 pairs like the above.
I tried using Map but map keys cannot contain duplicates.
Is there any other way i can store these value pairs in java script?

My function using map variable:

```
function repository()
{
var snakeRepo = new Map();
var xRepo,yRepo,count=0;
for (xRepo = 305;xRepo <=1085;xRepo=xRepo+15)
{
    for (yRepo = 55;yRepo <=535;yRepo=yRepo+15)
        {
            snakeRepo.set(xRepo,yRepo);
            //console.log(xRepo+","+yRepo);
            count=count+1;
        }
}
console.log(snakeRepo);
}
```

Comment: `var a = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3]...]`?

Comment: please add how you like to access the data.

Comment: As George said, or `var a = [];` `a.push([1,1]);` (as per your preference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an array inside of an array or objects inside of the array.

**Array inside the array**

```
var arrayInArray = [[1,2], [3,4]];
```

and you can access the values inside the array with:

```
//where 0 is the index of the values you want    
arrayInArray[0]; //returns [1, 2];
```

**Objects inside the array**

```
var objectInArray = [{firstID: 1, secondID: 2},{firstID: 3, secondID: 4}];
```

and you casn access the values insde with:

```
where 0 is the index of the object you want
objectInArray[0]; //returns an object {firstID: 1, secondID: 2}
//alternatively, you can access your object's values by adding a dot
objectInArray[0].firstID; // returns 1
```

To save the date inside the array you can use

```
arrayInArray.push([1,2]);
objectInArray.push({id1: 1,id2: 2});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you want to use it after, but you can store them as object individually ? Then push them in an array if you want :

```
var pair = {
  value1 : 1,
  value2 : 2
}
```

If values are generated in a for loop, it will be easy to use like this.

Comment: Since the keys don't appear to be unique… probably not.

Comment: How do you store the pairs `1, 1` and `1, 2` in that object?

Comment: var res = [];
var p1 = { value1 : 1, value2 : 1};
res.push(p1);
var p2 = { value1 : 1, value2: 2};
res.push(p2);

Comment: I will not do all cases like this.
As I said, I don't know how he generates his values neither how he would use it.
But no problems here.

Comment: I see now what you're actually saying. I'd rather suggest the use of an array instead of objects though, as `var pair = [1,1]`. Using an object seems overly verbose for what is essentially just a tuple.

Comment: Ok you're probably right, depending on his usecase.
It could also be easily read with real name property in my object (like "key", "value")